# Is there a web application equivalent of Hypercard?

Tags: hypercard

Recently, I found an interesting Wiki/CMS/Database hybrid called Wagn, where the most important unit of information is the 'Card'. That terminology immediately made me think of Hypercard. As expected, there is some "Hypercard-ness" in that application.

Do you know of other web applications/frameworks with that "Hypercard-ness" thing, or if its successor still must be invented?

Note: I insist on web applications because I already know the desktop ones.

Comment: Looks like TileStack went away, and alas they took their source with them instead of releasing it as abandonware..

Comment: hypercard.js (http://xkcd.com/1636/)

Comment: @Michael I gather that the first thing you did after reading that was to search "Hypercard.js", for which this is the only result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that quote from Dan Ingalls in the book "Coders At Work" (p.382):

"A decade or two ago there was Hypercard [...] It's really strange that that whole experience didn't naturally go right into the web. I think there's still a role to be filled there with tools as simple as HyperCard and as immediate as the web. It would be cool if it went that way.".

If one of the inventor of Smalltalk is asking that question too, I'm almost sure that there is no valid answers...

Anyone interested in inventing that future?

Answer (score 4):

Check out Runtime Revolution at http://www.runrev.com they have a language/IDE that is the spiritual successor to HyperCard. They also have a product in beta called RevWeb which is a plugin not unlike Flash that is able to execute stacks.

Now more on the web framework front, checkout Rodeo at http://alltiera.com/ which is a HyperCard like web application that generates HTML/CSS/JS stuff for you.

I am a customer of Runtime Revolution but I haven't used Rodeo so I can only help with building web applications using RevTalk (like HyperTalk) and not with Rodeo.

Comment: Rodeo is no more. You might want to delete the link.

Answer (score 2):

There was http://tilestack.com for a while. Sadly it closed down again. It even imported HyperCard stacks.

Answer (score 0):

Google's AppEngine is being called the web Hypercard.
http://www.skrenta.com/2008/04/appengine_web_hypercard_finall.html

Googel App Engine  - http://code.google.com/appengine/

Comment: Interesting article, but Google App Engine lacks the RAD tools offered by Hypercard. Anyway, the comments are mentioning several other technologies (such as Jaxter). I will check them.